# Visual Studio extension - creating project type

Tags: visual-studio-2012, vsix

I'm trying to create a new Visual Studio project type following the tutorial: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc512961.aspx

Unfortunately I'm getting a strange exception stating that "Guid should contain 32 digits and 4 dashes".

The error appears somewhere along the lines:

```
// Launch the aggregate creation process (we should be called back on our     
IVsAggregatableProjectFactoryCorrected implementation)
IVsCreateAggregateProject aggregateProjectFactory =IVsCreateAggregateProject)this.Site.GetService(typeof(SVsCreateAggregateProject));
        int hr = aggregateProjectFactory.CreateAggregateProject(guidsList, fileName, location, name, flags, ref projectGuid, out project);
        if(hr == VSConstants.E_ABORT)
            canceled = 1;
        ErrorHandler.ThrowOnFailure(hr);
```

I 've got no idea what I'm doing wrong and how to debug this. ErrorHandler just throws exception.

Comment: I guess that the guidsList variable contains an invalid guid (the `pszProjectTypeGuids` parameter expects a list of guids, or at least a single guid; maybe one of them is of an invalid format).

Comment: Finally I was able to debug this issue - the problem was that in the project template there was variable $guid1$ that was probably meant to be substituted, but for some reason was passed to new Guid(string) and threw this exception. I wasn't able to figure out what is the correct thing to do, but I'll examine IronPython source to get to know.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx) in VS Extensibility walkthrough](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23959642/guid-should-contain-32-digits-with-4-dashes-xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx)